# Finding Max/Min Without Using Array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a Summary tab in an Excel file that needs to look at an Accruals tab to find a `Max` and `Min`. The problem I am having is that there are many different Location/Commodity combinations and I need to find the `Max` and `Min` based on the Location/Commodity combination. Location and Commodity are in two separate columns.

For example, `location 123` can have a `commodity` of `01`, `02`, and `03`. `Location 123 Commodity 01` can have several different prices. I need to look up `location 123`, `commodity 01` and find the max of those prices.

I have been asked not to use an `array` as it slows the files down. I was previously attempting to use `=MAX(IF())` but that was not preferred.

How can I find values on the Accruals tab based on the location column AND the commodity column matching from the Summary tab and then get the max of those values based on the loc/comm combination? Is there a more simple way through VBA? I was trying to write a loop but I am not very advanced and having some difficulty.

Comment: Sounds more like a use-case for pivot tables (where you can group your data in various ways then apply summary functions such as `max` and `min` to the resulting groups) than for VBA

Comment: If you have Office 365 or Excel 2019+, you can use the [MAXIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

Comment: This very much looks like a job for a pivot table.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how large ranges are in your data and what exact array you had in mind. Using whole columns slow down things a LOT! There are ways to minimize this by using dynamic ranges to make it perfectly workable.

Comment: @JvdV, the Summary tab will have around 60 loc/comm combos. The Accruals tab can have up to 10,000 entries of values for these combos.

Comment: @twils14, while that's a lot, it's still way less than the over a milion rows an array formula would check when teh wrong ranges are applied. Agreed that it's still a lot and probably slow.

Comment: Import the data into an actual database (or does it come from one?), and make a view / write SQL to perform the aggregates. Or bring it into a PowerQuery data model. This is a problem you need to address *as a data set*, not as individual records. VBA would be terribly inefficient for this.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't really thought about a pivot table. My prior experience with those haven't been great, but this seems to be able to give me exactly what I need.

I created two pivot tables - one for max, one for min and then used the GETPIVOTDATA() function on the Summary tab to pull in those values based on location and commodity combination.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Consider importing the source of these pivots into "Get & Transform" / PowerQuery - you can use it to make a refreshable summary that computes both min and max aggregates, rather easily.